# Create a service proxy handler in an ASP.NET control library to prevent cross domain requests

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf, xss

I have created a ASP.NET library that contains several custom server controls to enable reuse of common functionality across several web applications. A couple of the controls rely on a web service to query for data (e.g. a HR web service that you can search for an employee). The server controls generate/register JavaScript on the client an I use jQuery to create an extension to do the client side heavy lifting.

I cannot guarantee that the web service will be on the same domain as the application, and so I am trying to determine the best way to avoid cross domain AJAX requests without having to request modifications to the users browser settings. I would also like to avoid requiring other developers to add proxies manually to their applications.

I figure that I need to create a proxy service in my library, and register the handler via code in my library, or I need to create a handler when they add the library to their application via NuGet.

I've tried searching for information on doing this, and while there is plenty of information on proxies, etc. I can't find any information to do what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I have managed to solve this specific problem using a reverse proxy created with URL Rewrite 2.0 but I would still be interested in an answer to how the above could be achieved as it might be handy in the future if you wanted to put a handler into a library.